# Angular 2 How to access array value by key name in a template expression

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have this object I'm trying to acces in Angular 2 template expression:

```
   "purchMgt" : {
        "psas" : [ 
            {
                "psaEffective" : ISODate("2014-09-09T07:00:00.000Z"),
                "psaConsentNote" : "Yes",
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have tried many iterations of the following:

```
<p>Title Issue 1 - Consent to Assign Required {{purchMgt?.psas?[0].psaConsentNote || '--'}}</p>
```

or like this:

```
<p>Title Issue 1 - Consent to Assign Required {{purchMgt?.psas?[0]?.psaConsentNote || '--'}}</p>
```

or:

```
<p>Title Issue 1 - Consent to Assign Required {{purchMgt?.psas?[psaConsentNote] || '--'}}</p>
```

and also:

```
<p>Title Issue 1 - Consent to Assign Required {{purchMgt?.psas?["psaConsentNote"] || '--'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works but if there is a better way I'll give accepted answer:

On html

```
<strong>{{psaParser(project?.realEstate?.purchMgt?.psas, 'psaConsentNote') || '--'}}</strong>
```

On component

```
public psaParser(psa, key) {

    if (psa) {
        return psa[0][key];

    } else {

        return null;
    }
}
```